# Add row to Sublist

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

How can I add a new row to a forms sublist? I am working with a SuiteScript 2.0 Suitelet. Any advice would be extremely helpful.

```
function initForm(context) {

    var form = ui.createForm({
        title: 'Generate Lab Request File'
    });

    var sublist = form.addSublist({
        id: 'sublist', 
        type: ui.SublistType.LIST, //.INLINEEDITOR, 
        label: 'Panels'
    });
    sublist.addField({
        id: 'export_version', 
        type: ui.FieldType.FLOAT, 
        label: 'Export Version'});

    // Fails because row 1 doesn't exist. How can I add a new row?
    sublist.setSublistValue({
        id : 'export_version',
        line : 1,   // I'm trying to add a new row. I already have row 0
        value : "6.0"
    });

    // Error function doesn't exist
    sublist.addRows({
        rows: [{export_version : '6.0'},
            {export_version : '6.0'}]
    });


    context.response.writePage(form);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good example in the SuiteScript 2.0 API docs.  You just need to select a new line.  I noted it in the sample script below.  Hope that helps.

```js
**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 */
require(['N/record'], function(record) {
    function createPurchaseOrder() {
        var rec = record.create({
            type: 'purchaseorder',
            isDynamic: true
        });
        rec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'entity',
            value: 52
        });
        rec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'location',
            value: 2
        });
        /******/
        //Here is where you are adding a new line.
        /******/
        rec.selectNewLine({
            sublistId: 'item'
        });
        rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'item',
            value: 190
        });
        rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'quantity',
            value: 2
        });
        subrecordInvDetail = rec.getCurrentSublistSubrecord({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'inventorydetail'
        });
        subrecordInvDetail.selectNewLine({
            sublistId: 'inventoryassignment'
        });
        subrecordInvDetail.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
            fieldId: 'receiptinventorynumber',
            value: 'myinventoryNumber'
        });
        subrecordInvDetail.commitLine({
            sublistId: 'inventoryassignment'
        });
        subrecordInvDetail.selectLine({
            sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
            line: 0
        });
        var myInventoryNumber = subrecordInvDetail.getCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
            fieldId: 'receiptinventorynumber'
        });
    }
    createPurchaseOrder();
});
```